# Android animation wrong coordinates

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to make a splash screen like FB's app, where the logo moves up and the login stuff appears. I don't know why, but this doesn't work properly:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
ImageView logo;
int width, height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (logo != null) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x / 2;
        height = size.y / 2;

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(width, width,
                height, height / 2);
        animation.setDuration(2500);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener());

        logo.startAnimation(animation);
        // /////
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        logo.clearAnimation();
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(logo.getWidth(),
                logo.getHeight());
        lp.setMargins((int) width, (int) height / 2, 0, 0);
        logo.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

}
```

}

I'm trying to move an ImageView vertically, starting from the screen's center:

```
  width = size.x / 2;
  height = size.y / 2;
```

Instead of that, the ImageView moves vertically from right bottom corner. 
 1. Why dividing the screen size / 2 doesn't position the ImageView in the center of it?
 2. After the animation ends, I set the new LayoutParams to the ImageView: `lp.setMargins((int) width, (int) height / 2, 0, 0);`. Shouldn't that position it in the place that the animation ends? Instead of that, it's getting pushed to the left.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".Login" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [If you can, please avoid splashscreens!](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Comment: Agreed with @StackOverflowException. Whenever I see an animated splash screen, I know what the author of the app decided to spent time on.

Comment: Ok, I won't :P Besides that, any idea of why the coordinates result in such a failed animation?